# A strange difference between "which" and "what"

Tags: word-difference

Suppose, my friend and I discuss Manx cats and American Shorthairs. Then I definitely can ask:

"Which cats are more and which are less attractive?"

Now, suppose we speak of cats *in general*. There may be infinitely many different cats and it seems natural to ask:

"What cats are more and what are less attractive?"

However, Google finds only 2 instances of "more and what are less" (against 4,060,000 results for  "more and which are less").

I understand that this is a matter of idiomaticity, but maybe there is a clear explanation of what is wrong with the 2nd question?

Comment: Sort of an obnoxious example, you provide. In this day and age, a question like that is not politically correct. That said, you are allowed to like whomever you like. But which and what have zero to do with the number of some thing in general. Which are more attractive: large, long-haired dogs or small, short-haired dogs?

Comment: >  which and what have zero to do with the number of some thing in general. 
Are You serious? The Oxford Dictionary says about "which": "used in questions and statements having a limited number of possibilities"

Comment: "Idiomaticity" is _almost_ the correct word to describe it...

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with either question. Pronouns take their number from their referents, and both _which_ and _what_ have the plural _cats_ here, so the verb _are_ is correct. Idiomatically, we prefer to use "which" when we choose from among defined options. We use "what" when the options are not defined.

Comment: Yes, from your words it follows, indeed, that there is nothing wrong with the 2nd construction. But why it is not used (absolutely!) in such a case?

Comment: Because _Idiomatically, we prefer to use "which" when we choose from among defined options._ It's just the way we say such things in English.

Comment: Yes, you said it before. And I quoted the dictionary which says the same. So, I *understand* that. What I *don't* understand is what it has to do with my question. Are you saying that in the second case options are defined??

Comment: Oh, now I see. No, we use "which" in _both_ such cases just because it's idiomatic. If one were to think about it, yes, in the second case "what cats are..." would make sense. But we just don't use that construction, as you noticed. That's what makes it idiomatic.